# ElasticSearch Edge NGram vs Prefix query

Tags: elasticsearch, prefix, n-gram

Let's say we have a text field that is relatively short, let's say maximum 10 characters and is saved as a keyword.
I want my users to be able to prefix-search this field (not autocomplete / search-as-you-type).
[I have read on Elastic's documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/prefix-query.html) that the prefix query scales poorly, and they give a couple of examples to demonstrate it.

**When is it ok to use prefix search, and when should I use index-time edge-ngrams?** Building and storing index-time edge-ngrams of this field sounds excessive, but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4):

First thing first:

> Keyword fields are only searchable by their exact value

Thus you can't prefix-search a field that is defined as **keyword type** . prefix-search is only work for analyzed fields.

In general prefix-search has relatively poor performance. You can improve it's functionality by ***index_prefixes*** but even then it is relatively intense operation so if you plan to scale your business, it is better to use **N-Grams** because it is more resource efficient.